# Icon Change in PDFComment

Tags: pdfcomment

Whether it possible to change the pre-defined icon to any user defined symbol in PDFcomment package.

Eg: I would like to load a arrow from symbol font or some other font as icon and then it used be click to open the comment.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible. Different PDF viewers have different sets of icons. OTOH, i have never read the PDF Reference completely. Therefore i might be wrong.

But you can use PDF Markup Comments to construct something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage%[final]
{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\phoneicon[2][0pt]%
{%
  \ifpc@gopt@final\else%
    \hbox to 0pt%
    {%
      \fboxsep.6pt%
      \fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\pdfmarkupcomment[opacity=0,color=yellow,author=Comment]{\phone}{#2}}%
    }%
    \hspace{#1}
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test\phoneicon[10pt]{This s a test!} foo bar
\end{document}
```

[image: phone icon]